# How to display hidden field along with values using .as_hidden?

Tags: django

In django, 
We can convert a form field to hidden as shown below.

```
{{ form.user.as_hidden  }}
```

This will display a hidden field, with name as user. But it won't assign any value to it? How we can set an initial value for this field?

Tried

```
{{ form.user.as_hidden  value="1"}}
```

But it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`initial`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values) parameter. As said in the docs:

> Use `initial` to declare the initial value of form fields at runtime. For example, you might want to fill in a `username` field with the username of the current session.

**There are two ways of doing it:**

Passing it to the form constructor:

```
form = UserForm(initial={'user': 1})
```

or setting the value in the form definition:

```
user = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial=1)
```

*Note*: You should edit your field to correspond to the user.